# Double List Comprehension in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension

I'm trying to implement an array as a list of lists in Haskell. In particular, I have some array `m` that I'm given, and a predicate `p` that I want to be satisfied, and I want to create a list of indices `(x,y)` such that the `x`th element of the `y`th list satisfies `p`. I set this up as the following list comprehension:

```
[(x,y) | x<-[1..],y<-[1..],p ((m !! y) !! x)]
```

Which throws up an error when it tries to find an element of `m` in the first row that doesn't exist. I can see one immediate way to fix this is to just change the inner comprehensions on `x` and `y` to something like `y<-[1..length m]` but I feel like there's a cuter way that exploits laziness. I just don't know what it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed there is. The common idiom for getting list elements together with their indices is to use `zip`:

```
[(x,y) | (x,mx) <- zip [1..] m, (y,mxy) <- zip [1..] mx, p mxy]
```

Also:

- `!!` is quite inefficient, especially when extracting many elements from a list, so it's best to try to avoid it when possible.
- List indices usually start with `0` in Haskell.

Comment: Aha! I didn't know `!!` was particularly inefficient either, thanks for that.

Comment: @DanielLittlewood Keep in mind that Haskell lists are **linked** structures. The operation `xs !! n` requires to walk for `n` links to obtain the element. This is in  contrast to usual indexing of arrays in most imperative languages were it would require O(1) operations.